# Run time error '424': Object required with webscrape

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the 37.59% from a website using VBA:-

```
<span id="dgCompShare_Label23_5">37.59%</span>
```

I have managed to navigate to the site and make various selections. The following is my relevant VBA code.

```
Dim appIE As Object
Dim f As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Macro2")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
.Navigate "https://website.com/"
.Visible = True


    Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Loop

Set f = appIE.document.getElementbyid("dgCompShare_Label23_5")
    If Not f Is Nothing Then percent = f.innerText

    With ws
    .Cells(4, 3) = percent
    End With
```

I receive Run time error '424': Object required  at:
 Set f = appIE.document.getElementbyid("dgCompShare_Label23_5")
I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: try adding the `.readystate` check to this `Do While appIE.Busy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens when the page is not loaded fully or loaded internally and you try to set an object.

If you are sure that the element you are looking for is available on the html page, give this a try and see if this works for you.

```
On Error Resume Next
Do While appIE.Busy And f Is Nothing
    DoEvents
    Set f = appIE.document.getElementbyid("dgCompShare_Label23_5")
Loop

Percent = f.innerText
```

Or also check the ReadyState of the ieApp object and then set the object variable...

```
Do While appIE.busy Or appid.readystate <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
Set f = appIE.document.getElementbyid("dgCompShare_Label23_5")
```

Comment: Thanks. Confused me because it was an intermittent error.